# Simple function does not work for `dcast` - reshape2

Tags: r, reshape

Suppose I have this data:

```
 c1 c2 c3
 A  A  AA
 A  B  BB
 A  C  CC
 B  A  DD
 B  B  EE
 B  C  FF
 C  A  GG
 C  B  HH
 C  C  II
 A  A  JJ
```

I want to reshape them with `dcast` with this function:

```
dcast(data,c1~c2,value.var="c3",function(x)x)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be length 0,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

How can use a new function with `dcast` (User defined function).

I want to get:

```
  A   B   C
A AA BB  CC
B DD EE  FF
C GG HH  II
A JJ NA  NA
```

Comment: Whats `function(x)x`? What is your desired output?

Comment: A dummy function to return the `value.var` without change.

Comment: Just `dcast(stocksm,time~stock,value.var="price")`?

Comment: It returns the length of variable, because of duplicated rows in my real dataset.

Comment: So what do you want to return when there is a duplicate then?

Comment: Put some characters like NA.

Comment: So please make your example reproducible and provide your exact desired output.

Comment: Isn't there should be `JJ` in the last row?

Comment: @Henrik Alright, I deleted the answer. Happy :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table`s v 1.9.5+ new `rleid` function, which will create an index for the `c1` column (you can remove `indx` afterwards if you want)

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(stocksm)[, indx := rleid(c1)], indx + c1 ~ c2, value.var = "c3")
#    indx c1  A  B  C
# 1:    1  A AA BB CC
# 2:    2  B DD EE FF
# 3:    3  C GG HH II
# 4:    4  A JJ NA NA

### installing the development version
# library(devtools)
# install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

---

So basically after creating an index on `c1` we are spreading the data more or less as before, while including `indx` inside

---

Or if you insist on `tidyr`, here's an option

```
library(tidyr)
stocksm$indx <- with(rle(as.character(stocksm$c1)), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
spread(stocksm, c2, c3)
#   c1 indx  A    B    C
# 1  A    1 AA   BB   CC
# 2  A    4 JJ <NA> <NA>
# 3  B    2 DD   EE   FF
# 4  C    3 GG   HH   II
```

Comment: `tidyr` package has `spread` function, can it produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `dcast` is to create unique identifiers with `cumsum`. The function will not know which value to fill in for duplicates like `A A` if it isn't created.

```
data$ids <- cumsum(c(T,diff(as.numeric(data$c1)) != 0L))
dcast(data, ids+c1~c2, value.var="c3")[-1]
#   c1  A    B    C
# 1  A AA   BB   CC
# 2  B DD   EE   FF
# 3  C GG   HH   II
# 4  A JJ <NA> <NA>
```